# Why running Cucumber test with Maven return result "Tests run: 0"?

Tags: eclipse, maven, junit, cucumber-jvm

I am using Maven in Eclipse to run Cucumber test. The project structure is as follows:

[image]

I used below Junit runner

```
@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(
features={"src/test/resources/feature"}
,glue={"test.java.stepdefinition"}
)
public class CucumberJunitTest {
}
```

The test seems running fine. It's printing the correct log for scenario and steps.

```
-------------------------------------------------------
 T E S T S
-------------------------------------------------------
Running test.java.cucumberjunit.CucumberJunitTest
a global administrator named
Successful Login with Valid Credentials: 1
Successful Login with Valid Credentials: 2
Successful Login with Valid Credentials: 3
Successful Login with Valid Credentials: 4

1 Scenarios ([32m1 passed[0m)
5 Steps ([32m5 passed[0m)
0m0.206s

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.85 sec - in test.java.cucumberjunit.CucumberJunitTest

Results :

Tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0

[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 11.794 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-11-26T22:52:07+11:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 14M/191M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

However, what bothers me is that it says **Tests run: 0,**???

I figured there must be something wrong. But what could be the reason?

BTW, just to verify, i tried to add another TestNG runner in the project:

```
@CucumberOptions(
features = {"src/test/resources/feature"}
,glue={"test.java.stepdefinition"}
)

public class CucumberTestNGPest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
}
```

and the TestNG runner is printing Tests run: 1 as expected.

Could anyone provide any thoughts? Many thanks.

UPDATE:

To clarify, CucumberJunitTest.java and CucumberTestNGTest.java (In attached screenshot CucumberTestNGTest.java name is changed to CucumberTestNGPest.java so that Surefire will not run it this time) are both Cucumber runners. I do not understand why JUnit test can not give the "Test run: 1" result, where TestNG test can.

Answer (score 2):

You have testng and junit as well as dependencies. Try to use only junit so maven results won't be overwritten.

The minimal dependency list i needed in my pom afterall:

```
<properties>
    <properties>
    <junit.version>4.11</junit.version>
    <selenium.version>2.50.1</selenium.version>
    <cucumber.version>1.2.0</cucumber.version>
</properties>


<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>${junit.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>info.cukes</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Comment: the pom.xml that you said would have the same error, it does not contain TestNG dependency. I only see junit and cucumber-junit. are u meant to said junit/cucumber-junit conflict, or junit/testNG conflict?

Comment: I mean junit-testNg conflict. What do you have in your pom? This that i showed is an example of a working one.
Also there can be other configurations that can be missing for example if Scenario list is not shown in maven log that it is another issue.
Well.. do you have a specific question user15...?

Answer (score 0):

I think one this missing and it is result plugin. I think this can fix issue.

```
@CucumberOptions(plugin = { "pretty","json:target/stepdefinition.json" }
features = {"src/test/resources/feature"}
,glue={"test.java.stepdefinition"}
)

public class CucumberTestNGPest extends AbstractTestNGCucumberTests{
}
```